# How to subset a DataFrame, using loc(), based on multiple columns having a particular value with Python?

Tags: python, pandas

If I want to create a subset of a DataFrame, based on a condition where a specified column can have multiple specified values, I can do this:

```
df = df.loc[df[column_name].isin(list_of_acceptable_values)]
```

If I have a list of column names, what is the best way to create a subset of a DataFrame, based on a condition, which checks if these columns contain a particular value. For example, the list of column names is:

```
['column_1', 'column_2', 'column_3']
```

And I want to create a new DataFrame, which only has rows from the initial dataframe that contain 0 in column_1, column_2 or column_3

Comment: `df[(df[list_of_cols] == 0).any(axis=1)]` should work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass a list of the column names of interest to subset, then compare with `0` and test for any col values for a row using [`any(axis=1)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
In [9]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,0],'b':[1,1,1,1],'c':[1,0,1,1]})
df

Out[9]:
   a  b  c
0  1  1  1
1  1  1  0
2  1  1  1
3  0  1  1

In [10]:
df[(df[['a','c']]==0).any(axis=1)]

Out[10]:
   a  b  c
1  1  1  0
3  0  1  1
```

For the case where you have a predefined list you don't need to enclose again using square brackets:

```
In [12]:
col_list = ['a','c']
df[(df[col_list]==0).any(axis=1)]

Out[12]:
   a  b  c
1  1  1  0
3  0  1  1
```

Comment: Great answer, thanks. A problem I'm having is that I can't do it this way when the list values are not known in advance. E.g. columns_list = ['cooking', 'pets'] df[(df[[columns_list]]==0).any(axis=1)] gives me a TypeError: unhashable list. I need to pass a pre-populated list. Sorry for not being clearer in the question.

Comment: See updated answer, basically if you already have a list then you don't need the additional square brackets